# Opencv Object Detection? (avoid object)

Tags: python, opencv, object

I was wondering if anyone knows how to detect an object, located in a known scenario. 
Basically I have this camera moving around and there will probably be obstacles. The goal is to avoid those obstacles. Do you think there is a way to find out where this objects is and how far it is? I don't know how big the object is, but I have access to the camera matrix. (and also everything that can be calculated)EDIT : The camera is monocular. 
Sorry for my English. It's not my native language

EDIT

This is the kind of object i have to avoid(it can have also the another shape!)
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOEiE.jpg)

Comment: You should provide example images. Otherwise it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Instead of detecting objecs in your way, you could try detecting the black line.
If the black line get's lost their probablly is an obstacle. 
For me this looks like a robots competition. 
I recommend that you focus on pathfinding algorithms additonal to image processing.

Comment: Yeah that is the solution we are going for.. But I wanted to know if it was possible maybe to detect an object that shouldnt be there or something like that. Do you think that it is possible?